# InvalidArgumentError (see above for traceback): You must feed a value for placeholder tensor 'Placeholder' with dtype float and shape [360,480,3]

Tags: python, tensorflow, placeholder

I will conduct the test using the code below to test the Tensorflow-based E-Net on a real-time webcam.

However, placeholder errors occur in the 78th line of code.

An error occurs in the locationholder if the image is prefixedicized using the code below.

The video file for the experiment is a (480, 360)sized color image (360,480,3) and an avi-file of the MJPG codec.

What is the placeholder? 
How can I solve this?

help me plz..

**Here is the Error code.**

```
True
HERE (1, 360, 480)
WARNING:tensorflow:From predict_video.py:102: Supervisor.__init__ (from tensorflow.python.training.supervisor) is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.
Instructions for updating:
Please switch to tf.train.MonitoredTrainingSession
2018-09-13 14:11:41.510826: I c:\users\user\source\repos\tensorflow\tensorflow\core\platform\cpu_feature_guard.cc:140] Your CPU supports instructions that this TensorFlow binary was not compiled to use: AVX AVX2
2018-09-13 14:11:42.140975: I c:\users\user\source\repos\tensorflow\tensorflow\core\common_runtime\gpu\gpu_device.cc:1356] Found device 0 with properties:
name: GeForce GTX 960M major: 5 minor: 0 memoryClockRate(GHz): 1.176
pciBusID: 0000:01:00.0
totalMemory: 4.00GiB freeMemory: 3.34GiB
2018-09-13 14:11:42.162310: I c:\users\user\source\repos\tensorflow\tensorflow\core\common_runtime\gpu\gpu_device.cc:1435] Adding visible gpu devices: 0
2018-09-13 14:11:43.001599: I c:\users\user\source\repos\tensorflow\tensorflow\core\common_runtime\gpu\gpu_device.cc:923] Device interconnect StreamExecutor with strength 1 edge matrix:
2018-09-13 14:11:43.013639: I c:\users\user\source\repos\tensorflow\tensorflow\core\common_runtime\gpu\gpu_device.cc:929]      0
2018-09-13 14:11:43.020308: I c:\users\user\source\repos\tensorflow\tensorflow\core\common_runtime\gpu\gpu_device.cc:942] 0:   N
2018-09-13 14:11:43.029139: I c:\users\user\source\repos\tensorflow\tensorflow\core\common_runtime\gpu\gpu_device.cc:1053] Created TensorFlow device (/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0 with 3075 MB memory) -> physical GPU (device: 0, name: GeForce GTX 960M, pci bus id: 0000:01:00.0, compute capability: 5.0)
WARNING:tensorflow:Standard services need a 'logdir' passed to the SessionManager
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\zmqp1\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py", line 1322, in _do_call
    return fn(*args)
  File "C:\Users\zmqp1\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py", line 1307, in _run_fn
    options, feed_dict, fetch_list, target_list, run_metadata)
  File "C:\Users\zmqp1\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py", line 1409, in _call_tf_sessionrun
    run_metadata)
**tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError: You must feed a value for placeholder tensor 'Placeholder' with dtype float and shape [360,480,3]**
         [[Node: Placeholder = Placeholder[dtype=DT_FLOAT, shape=[360,480,3], _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0"]()]]
         [[Node: Placeholder/_2837 = _Recv[client_terminated=false, recv_device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0", send_device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0", send_device_incarnation=1, tensor_name="edge_4_Placeholder", tensor_type=DT_FLOAT, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"]()]]

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "predict_video.py", line 113, in <module>
    print('~~~~~~~~~~~~~~',sess.run(image_tensor))
  File "C:\Users\zmqp1\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py", line 900, in run
    run_metadata_ptr)
  File "C:\Users\zmqp1\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py", line 1135, in _run
    feed_dict_tensor, options, run_metadata)
  File "C:\Users\zmqp1\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py", line 1316, in _do_run
    run_metadata)
  File "C:\Users\zmqp1\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py", line 1335, in _do_call
    raise type(e)(node_def, op, message)
**tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError: You must feed a value for placeholder tensor 'Placeholder' with dtype float and shape [360,480,3]**
         [[Node: Placeholder = Placeholder[dtype=DT_FLOAT, shape=[360,480,3], _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0"]()]]
         [[Node: Placeholder/_2837 = _Recv[client_terminated=false, recv_device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0", send_device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0", send_device_incarnation=1, tensor_name="edge_4_Placeholder", tensor_type=DT_FLOAT, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"]()]]

Caused by op 'Placeholder', defined at:
  File "predict_video.py", line 78, in <module>
    image_tensor = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[H,W,3])
  File "C:\Users\zmqp1\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\array_ops.py", line 1808, in placeholder
    return gen_array_ops.placeholder(dtype=dtype, shape=shape, name=name)
  File "C:\Users\zmqp1\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\gen_array_ops.py", line 5835, in placeholder
    "Placeholder", dtype=dtype, shape=shape, name=name)
  File "C:\Users\zmqp1\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\op_def_library.py", line 787, in _apply_op_helper
    op_def=op_def)
  File "C:\Users\zmqp1\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\ops.py", line 3392, in create_op
    op_def=op_def)
  File "C:\Users\zmqp1\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\ops.py", line 1718, in __init__
    self._traceback = self._graph._extract_stack()  # pylint: disable=protected-access

**InvalidArgumentError (see above for traceback): You must feed a value for placeholder tensor 'Placeholder' with dtype float and shape [360,480,3]**
         [[Node: Placeholder = Placeholder[dtype=DT_FLOAT, shape=[360,480,3], _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0"]()]]
         [[Node: Placeholder/_2837 = _Recv[client_terminated=false, recv_device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0", send_device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0", send_device_incarnation=1, tensor_name="edge_4_Placeholder", tensor_type=DT_FLOAT, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"]()]]
```

**Here is the my code.**

```
import tensorflow as tf
import os
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from enet import ENet, ENet_arg_scope
from preprocessing import preprocess
from scipy.misc import imsave
import numpy as np
import cv2
import time

slim = tf.contrib.slim

os.environ["CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES"]="0"

W = 480
H = 360

batch_size = 1
num_classes = 7

video_dir = './data/'
fname = 'bottom.avi'

checkpoint_dir = "./log/original/"
checkpoint = tf.train.latest_checkpoint(checkpoint_dir)

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(video_dir+fname)
print(cap.isOpened())

num_initial_blocks = 1
skip_connections = False
stage_two_repeat = 2

label_to_colours =  {0: [0,255,0],
                     1: [0,255,255],
                     2: [0,0,255],
                     3: [0,150,150],
                     4: [255,255,0],
                     5: [255,0,0],
                     6: [255,255,255]}

#Create the photo directory
photo_dir = checkpoint_dir + "/test_images"
if not os.path.exists(photo_dir):
    os.mkdir(photo_dir)

def vis_segmentation(image, seg_map):
    """Visualizes input image, segmentation map and overlay view."""
    image_width, image_height = image.size
    colored_label = label_to_color_image(seg_map).astype(np.uint8)
    image_empty = np.zeros((image_height,2*image_width,3),np.uint8)
    image_empty[:image_height,:image_width] = image.copy()
    image_empty[:image_height,image_width:] = colored_label.copy()
    image_empty[:image_height,:image_width] = image.copy()
    image_empty[:image_height,image_width:] = colored_label.copy()

    alpha = 0.35
    beta = 1-alpha
    gamma = 0
    img_add = cv2.addWeighted(np.array(image), alpha, seg_map, beta, gamma)
    return img_add

#Create a function to convert each pixel label to colour.
def grayscale_to_colour(image):
    print('Converting image...')
    image = image.reshape((H, W, 1))
    image = np.repeat(image, 3, axis=-1)
    for i in range(image.shape[0]):
        for j in range(image.shape[1]):
            label = int(image[i][j][0])
            image[i][j] = np.array(label_to_colours[label])

    return image

def model_run(image):   
    return predictions   
with tf.Graph().as_default() as graph:
    image_tensor = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[H,W,3])
    #image_tensor = tf.reshape(image_tensor, shape=(H,W,3))
    images = tf.expand_dims(image_tensor, 0)

    #Create the model inference
    with slim.arg_scope(ENet_arg_scope()):
        logits, probabilities = ENet(images,
                                 num_classes=num_classes,
                                 batch_size=batch_size,
                                 is_training=False,
                                 reuse=None,
                                 num_initial_blocks=num_initial_blocks,
                                 stage_two_repeat=stage_two_repeat,
                                 skip_connections=skip_connections)

    variables_to_restore = slim.get_variables_to_restore()
    saver = tf.train.Saver(variables_to_restore)
    def restore_fn(sess):
        return saver.restore(sess, checkpoint)

    predictions = tf.argmax(probabilities, -1)
    predictions = tf.cast(predictions, tf.float32)
    print('HERE', predictions.get_shape())

    sv = tf.train.Supervisor(logdir=None, init_fn=restore_fn)

    with sv.managed_session() as sess:
        now = 0.0
        while(cap.isOpened()):
            ret, frame = cap.read()
            if (ret == False):
                print('~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~did not get any frame~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~')
                break  
            image = frame.copy()             
            image = np.asarray(image, np.float32)/255          
            print('~~~~~~~~~~~~~~',sess.run(image_tensor))
            segmentations = sess.run(predictions, feed_dict={image_tensor:image})

            cv2.imshow('pre',segmentations[0])
            cv2.waitKey(0)

            #T = time.time() - now
            #print(int(1/T))
            #now = time.time()

cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is that you are violating a basic principle about using placeholders in TensorFlow.

Placeholders are meant to be fed, not evaluated like other ops.

The error traceback is clear as it goes to the following line in your code :

```
    print('~~~~~~~~~~~~~~',sess.run(image_tensor))
```

This is anyways inconsistent because, you could directly have printed `image`.

Comment: Oh, I got it. Thanks!